# JMeter - Using HTTP Request to test POST to upload and store a file

Tags: post, jmeter

I'm trying to use HTTP Request to upload and store a file via a POST to a REST api.  I can't use HTTP Raw because it is an https request.

I can successfully accomplish this with smaller files (<= 500 kb).  With larger files (>= 582 kb) it fails with a 500 Error: Connection error.  I know it is not an issue with my REST api because I can use POSTMAN and successfully post the same file.

These are images or audio recordings, not text files.

No errors appear in the jmeter logs.

Is there a setting controlling the size somewhere I haven't found?  Is there anyway to get this to work successfully?

Comment: Can you please increase the connection timeout in your HTTP request? Larger files utilizes your bandwidth, you should give ample time to JMeter to send the requests. Else, it will fail. Check this image please https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pxqL.png

Comment: I've increased the Connect timeouts and Response timeouts to 80000000 msecs.  I am still receiving the 500 Error.  It did work once in my testing but I couldn't reproduce it.  Still no errors in the jmeter logs.  This still works successfully with Postman (every time).  Any other ideas?

Comment: What is the maximum response size you will be getting for your requests? Thanks!

Comment: The highest I've seen reported by Postman is about 50 seconds.  thanks